# MathJax parentheses that span multiple lines

Tags: support, mathjax

In math.stackexchange.com, how do I get parentheses to span multiple lines?

For example, in

$$
x \neq y := x \neq x_{j+1}\\
\text{and}\\
\Big(y \not \in \textsf{FV}(A) := x_j \not \in \textsf{FV}(A)\\
\text{or}\\
x \not \in \textsf{FV}(M) := x \not \in \textsf{FV}(\lambda x_{j+1} \cdots x_n.B)\Big)
$$

can I get the left and right parenthesis each to span the last three lines?

---

MathJax for the above is:

```
$$
x \neq y := x \neq x_{j+1}\\
\text{and}\\
\Big(y \not \in \textsf{FV}(A) := x_j \not \in \textsf{FV}(A)\\
\text{or}\\
x \not \in \textsf{FV}(M) := x \not \in \textsf{FV}(\lambda x_{j+1} \cdots x_n.B)\Big)
$$
```

---

I know about using `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` to get a curly brace that spans multiple lines and am asking for something similar for a left and right parenthesis.

### Answers from comments

---

#### Use `\left \matrix{a \\ b} \right` (contributed by @XanderHenderson)

For example

```
$$
\left(
\matrix{
\text{here is a long formula}\\
\text{and}\\
\text{here is another long formula}}
\right)
$$
```

displays as

$$\left( \matrix{ \text{here is a long formula} \\ \text{and} \\ \text{here is another long formula} } \right)$$

---

#### Use `\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}` (contributed by @TheSimpliFire)

For example,

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{here is a long formula}\\
\text{and}\\
\text{here is another long formula}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

displays as

$$\begin{pmatrix} \text{here is a long formula} \\ \text{and} \\ \text{here is another long formula} \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Or are you looking for something more like $$\left( \matrix{ \text{here is a long formula} \\ \text{and} \\ \text{here is another long formula} }\right)?$$

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for TeX.SE.

Comment: Not exactly parentheses but `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}` on appearance does the job.

Comment: XanderHenderson and TheSimpliFire, thanks. I edited my question to include your answers.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire $$\left\{ \begin{matrix} \text{Yeah,} \\ \text{but if you use} \end{matrix} \right\|$$`\begin{matrix}. ... \end{matrix}`, $$\left[ \left. \begin{matrix} \text{you can use} \\ \text{whatever} \\ \text{delimiter you like!} \end{matrix} \right\rangle \right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use align and/or gather commands, rather than matrices or arrays.

For example:
$$\left(\begin{align*}
a&= 7+3\\
b+c&=d\\
&\text{and}\\
\exists y\forall xP(x,y)&\implies \forall x\exists y P(x,y)
\end{align*}\right)$$
is constructed with:

```
$$\left(\begin{align*}
 a&= 7+3\\
 b+c&=d\\
 &\text{and}\\
 \exists y\forall xP(x,y)&\implies \forall x\exists y P(x,y)
 \end{align*}\right)$$
```

which allows you align the equations. For example, you could also left justify them that way:
$$\left(\begin{align*}
 &a= 7+3\\
 &b+c=d\\
 &\text{and}\\
 &\exists y\forall xP(x,y)\implies \forall x\exists y P(x,y)
 \end{align*}\right)$$
obtained with

```
$$\left(\begin{align*}
 &a= 7+3\\
 &b+c=d\\
 &\text{and}\\
 &\exists y\forall xP(x,y)\implies \forall x\exists y P(x,y)
 \end{align*}\right)$$
```

You can also use arrays, which allow you to have multiple columns and align them left, right, or center. You do `\begin{array}{xxx}...\end{array}` where `{xxx}` should be one letter per column you want in the array, and each one giving you the type of alignment: `l` for left-aligned; `c` for centered, and `r` for right-aligned. For instance, `{llrcr}` would mean five columns, the first two left aligned, the third and fifth right-aligned, and the fourth centered.

The command `\begin{gather}...\end{gather}` also collects a bunch of lines and treats them as a single box, permitting the use of `\left` and `\right`.
For instance, for your formulas, you could do:
$$x \neq y := x \neq x_{j+1}\\
\text{and}\\
\left(
\begin{gather}
y \not \in \textsf{FV}(A) := x_j \not \in \textsf{FV}(A)\\
\text{or}\\
x \not \in \textsf{FV}(M) := x \not \in \textsf{FV}(\lambda x_{j+1} \cdots x_n.B)\end{gather}\right)$$
obtained with

```
$$x \neq y := x \neq x_{j+1}\\
\text{and}\\
\left(
  \begin{gather}
     y \not \in \textsf{FV}(A) := x_j \not \in \textsf{FV}(A)\\
     \text{or}\\
     x \not \in \textsf{FV}(M) := x \not \in \textsf{FV}(\lambda
        x_{j+1} \cdots x_n.B)
   \end{gather}
\right)$$
```

though, to be honest, I would probably try something like:
$$x \neq y := x \neq x_{j+1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\left(
\begin{gather}
y \not \in \textsf{FV}(A) := x_j \not \in \textsf{FV}(A)\\
\text{or}\\
x \not \in \textsf{FV}(M) := x \not \in \textsf{FV}(\lambda x_{j+1} \cdots x_n.B)
\end{gather}
\right)$$
which you get by removing the line breaks in the first two formulas and adding a `\quad` before and after the "and".

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. Went with the last one.

Comment: The proper sub-environments inside other math environments are `aligned` and `gathered`, mathjax is more forgiving here than "true" LaTeX.